# Adapter Pattern in SOA hexagonal/onion architecture

Tags: architecture, soa, onion-architecture, hexagonal-architecture

Assuming you have an application that requires 2 services, eg. `Application`, `Service1`, `Service2`

Should you build an extra level of indirection and promote 1 of the services to application service, and demote the other to domain service, following this [onion architecture](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/the-onion-architecture-part-1/).

Or should you have the `Application` directly connect to both `Service1` and `Service2`?

With another level of indirection, you can reduce dependency on the `Application` layer, especially towards external services eg. 'Paypal', 'Facebook', 'CyberSource' and create application service adapters that is more suitable for your programming paradigm. Afterall it is really detrimental to productivity having all developers familiarize themselves with all these widely varied APIs. A Façade/Adapter will make things easier to develop while shielding the application from infrastructural changes. eg.  The company had a failing out with CyberSource and decided to go with Paypal instead, luckily your application is shielded, and you only needed to change the adapter and nothing else.

That said, the adapter definitely creates inflexibility. As the application grows in complexity, the adapter also becomes leaky. Then you potentially have 3 problems: leaky abstraction, a lazy layer (a layer that's not doing enough due to having too many holes), and a violation of common closure principle, as anytime you need the UI changed, you have to modify not only your application, but also your adapters.

And what happen when `Service2` is already an internal service within the same company? Should you still create an adapter for each subsystem? What if your team is small? What if you have tens of teams with diverse set of technology? Is there any guidance for the propriety for adding another layer of indirection vs. just calling the service directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should design your application so that it **depends on interfaces that are convenient** to your application, independent of any consideration of using outside services. Your idea of using adapter/facade is a good one, but I don't see any reason to treat `Service1` any differently than `Service2`.

If my app is making widgets, then I should just call `MyService.MakeWidget(args);` The fact that this operation coordinates the behavior or 2 different external services is an implementation detail.

I think the convenience factor is more important than the goal of substituting external dependencies (although both are enabled by OA). Convenient interfaces improve the *narrative* of your application at the cost of indirection.